# Adding columns from a different SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to make a temporary table to put unrelated columns into to use later. I can create the table, and it will create the columns that I alter the table to have, however it will not update those columns with the data. I am using SQL Server 2014

```
SELECT * 
INTO testDB.dbo.t 
FROM Categories;

ALTER TABLE testDB.dbo.t 
ADD RegionID INT, RegionDescription varchar(255);

UPDATE testDB.dbo.t 
SET RegionID = Region.RegionID, 
    RegionDescription = Region.RegionDescription
FROM Region 
INNER JOIN t ON Region.RegionID = t.RegionID;
```

When I run this I get "error Object t not valid". Categories imports fine. Just trying to add those two columns from Region. Error is object t not found.

UPDATE for clarity since the original question was misleading.

I have:

```
CategorID |CategoryName |Description      |Picture        |RegionID |RegionDescr
1         |Beverages    |Soft drinks, teas|<BINARY DATA>  |NULL     |Null
```

I want:

`CategorID |CategoryName |Description         |Picture        |RegionID |RegionDescr
  1       |Beverages    |Soft drinks, teas   |<BINARY DATA>  |data*    |data*`

Where data is from another table in another database. There are not as many rows in the other database as categoryID's. Only categoryID is set to NOT NULL

Thanks for all  your help.

Comment: `UPDATE t SET ... FROM Region INNER JOIN testDB.dbo.t AS t ON ...`

Comment: Does one of the tables have more than one row for any given RegionID? Why? If you have one region in `Region` and multiple copies of that region in `Categories`, which one do you want? Maybe you would get to a solution faster if you show sample data in the two tables before the update (including duplicates and any other edge cases), then how you want the data to look afterward.

Comment: if you're creating one table in testDB and selecting from another db Northwind, just prefix your tables names with the dbname and schema.  `select * from Northwind.dbo.Region JOIN testDB.dbo.t` or it will only look in the currently connected db

Comment: I think your join is meaning to match on `CategoryID`, not `RegionID`. How can you join on a column you just added to the table and that is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query should be :

UPDATE t
SET RegionID = Region.RegionID, 
    RegionDescription = Region.RegionDescription
FROM Region 
INNER JOIN testDB.dbo.t t ON Region.RegionID = t.RegionID;

Comment: Thank you, Aaron was correct you can't join because data entries aren't an exact match.